# A pseudo force problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames

I got the following question in an app, while I was preparing for the exams.

> A wedge is placed on a smooth horizontal surface. Wedge contains a circular quadrant of radius 25 cm as shown. An insect crawls on the circular path with a constant speed 1/2 m/s. A force F is applied on the wedge, so that it does not move. Find the value of F in Newton when radial line of position of insect makes an angle 60° with the horizontal.

[image: A wedge is placed on a smooth horizontal surface. Wedge contains a circular quadrant of radius 25 cm as shown. An insect crawls on the circular path with a constant speed 1/2 m/s. A force F is applied on the wedge, so that it does not move. Find the value of F in Newton when radial line of position of insect makes an angle 60° with the horizontal.]

*My attempt*:

I have tried to resolve the forces so far. But, the problem comes with normal reaction and coefficent of friction, both of which are adjustable quantities and I can't figure out as much equations as there are variables.
! [image: my attempt]

Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. I don't want a solution, just a hint so that I can solve it myself.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just balance the forces in horizontal direction. 
Forces on the insect are the friction which is equal to the tangential component of weight, the normal and the normal component of the weight. The normal components cause the centripetal accn. You can get the normal and the friction from the fbd of the insect. Now look at the wedge. Resolve the contact forces applied by the insect horizontally. Applied force F balanced that.

Comment: Hi Ankan. Please do not answer homework questions. Thanks :-)